# How to display markers with distance and duration calculation in android studio maps

Tags: java, json, android-studio

I'm following this tutorial
Part1 https://codinginfinite.com/car-location-tracking-android-app-firebase-tutorial/ and 
Part2 https://codinginfinite.com/location-tracking-app-firebase-android-part-2/ for my app, however I need to display multiple markers/stops with the distance from the gps position to all these points/stops and also display the duration. How can I get it to work in the below link as reference and the link above.

https://goo.gl/maps/XkmdMDQPWSorcmHL9?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FirebaseDriverListener {
companion object {
    private const val MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 6161
    private const val ONLINE_DRIVERS = "online_drivers"
}
private lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap
private lateinit var locationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
private var locationFlag = true
private lateinit var valueEventListener: FirebaseEventListenerHelper
private val uiHelper = UiHelper()
private val googleMapHelper = GoogleMapHelper()
private val databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(ONLINE_DRIVERS)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val mapFragment: SupportMapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.supportMap) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync { googleMap = it }
    createLocationCallback()
    locationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    locationRequest = uiHelper.getLocationRequest()
    if (!uiHelper.isPlayServicesAvailable(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Play Services did not installed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        finish()
    } else requestLocationUpdate()
    valueEventListener = FirebaseEventListenerHelper(this)
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(valueEventListener)
}
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun requestLocationUpdate() {
    if (!uiHelper.isHaveLocationPermission(this)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        return
    }
    if (uiHelper.isLocationProviderEnabled(this))
        uiHelper.showPositiveDialogWithListener(this, resources.getString(R.string.need_location), resources.getString(R.string.location_content), object : IPositiveNegativeListener {
            override fun onPositive() {
                startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
            }
        }, "Turn On", false)
    locationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper())
}
private fun createLocationCallback() {
    locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
            if (locationResult!!.lastLocation == null) return
            val latLng = LatLng(locationResult.lastLocation.latitude, locationResult.lastLocation.longitude)
            Log.e("Location", latLng.latitude.toString() + " , " + latLng.longitude)
            if (locationFlag) {
                locationFlag = false
                animateCamera(latLng)
            }
        }
    }
}
private fun animateCamera(latLng: LatLng) {
    val cameraUpdate = googleMapHelper.buildCameraUpdate(latLng)
    googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, 10, null)
}
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) {
        val value = grantResults[0]
        if (value == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            finish()
        } else if (value == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) requestLocationUpdate()
    }
}
override fun onDriverAdded(driver: Driver) {
    val markerOptions = googleMapHelper.getDriverMarkerOptions(LatLng(driver.lat, driver.lng))
    val marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
    marker.tag = driver.driverId
    MarkerCollection.insertMarker(marker)
    totalOnlineDrivers.text = resources.getString(R.string.total_online_drivers).plus(" ").plus(MarkerCollection.allMarkers().size)
}
override fun onDriverRemoved(driver: Driver) {
    MarkerCollection.removeMarker(driver.driverId)
    totalOnlineDrivers.text = resources.getString(R.string.total_online_drivers).plus(" ").plus(MarkerCollection.allMarkers().size)
}
override fun onDriverUpdated(driver: Driver) {
    val marker = MarkerCollection.getMarker(driverId = driver.driverId)
    MarkerAnimationHelper.animateMarkerToGB(marker!!, LatLng(driver.lat, driver.lng), LatLngInterpolator.Spherical())
}
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener)
    locationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
    MarkerCollection.clearMarkers()
}
```

}